# jQuery mobile footer not always at bottom of screen

Tags: jquery-mobile

I'm working on a mobile phone app using jQuery mobile and phonegap. I'm using fixed footers and headers. Sometimes, after the keyboard has popped up, a space will appear between the footer bar and the keyboard. This space is the same as the background color, so I assume the footer is just shifting up for some reason. The behavior appears to be inconsistent, as it doesn't happen on all pages.

Here's a snippet of code...this code is the same for all pages but the gap is only on one page. The only difference between pages is the number of fields I have on the pages.

```
<div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed" class="ui-btn-right" style="min-height:42px;">
        <a href="#accident_menu" data-icon="arrow-l" data-direction="reverse" data-iconpos="left"
           style="margin-left: 10px; margin-top: 5px">Done</a>
        <a href="index.html" rel="external" data-icon="home" data-direction="reverse" data-iconpos="notext"
           style="float: right; margin-right: 10px; margin-top: 5px"></a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should consider to change to Jquery mobile 1.1.0 and their real fixed toolbars. [Read the announcement](http://jquerymobile.com/blog/2012/04/13/announcing-jquery-mobile-1-1-0/). Its supported by most of the devices in use and the most clean solution:

> The coolest part about this approach is that, unlike JS-based solutions that impose the unnatural scrolling physics across all platforms, our scrolling feels 100% native because it is. This means that scrolling feels right everywhere and **works with touch, mousewheel and keyboard user input.**

Comment: Thanks for this. We are using version 1.1.0. There was a problem on the CSS side and I applied some changes which helped to solve the problem.

Comment: I am using version 1.3, which is the lasted statable version. Why do I have the same problem? Should I roll back to use version 1.1.0?

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the similar problem, when the keyboard popup, the footer moves up. So I add the inline style with my footer. That worked for me.

```
<div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed" style="position:absolute">
```

> -->  "   style = "position:absolute"  "

that small part I add to my footer tag... and that worked perfectly. I hope that work for you.

Comment: Worked for what I needed.  Thanks, my entire app looks great throughout now.